# how to access child elements in a collection view?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview, collectionview

i am making frames in collection view and i want to change the background color of frames whenever i select the frames but the problem is that i cannot access my frames from the collection view and when i click on the frame it picks the default orange color.

i made small changes in my frame model class where i want to change text color of my label as like we did the color of frame  here is the code but it is not working 
 this code is in frame model class

```
public Color LabelColor
    {
        set
        {
            if (txtcolor != value)
            {
                txtcolor = value;

                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("labelcolor"));
                }
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return firstFrameBackColor;
        }
    }
```

here i access this in my CS Class

```
 FrameModel previous = (e.PreviousSelection.FirstOrDefault() as FrameModel);
        FrameModel current = (e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as FrameModel);

        //Set the current to the color you want
        try
        {
            current.FirstFrameBackColor = Color.FromRgb(74, 152, 247);
            current.LabelColor = Color.White;
            // current.SecondFrameBackColor = Color.Green;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.Message.ToString();
            throw;
        }

       // current.SecondFrameBackColor = Color.Green;

        if (previous != null)
        {
            //Reset the previous to defaulr color
            previous.FirstFrameBackColor = Color.White;
            current.LabelColor = Color.Black;
            //previous.SecondFrameBackColor = Color.Purple;
        }
```

Comment: where is the code where you are responding to a selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when i give x:name property to my child views inside the collection
>   view i cant access them in my C# class

You can't access items in templates from the code behind by name because there may be 0 or 1000 copies of that template created at run time.

Refer this discussion: [cannot-reach-control-x-name-inside-listview](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/82032/cannot-reach-control-x-name-inside-listview)

In your case, instead of access the control in the template, you can set the background property **binding** to the property in the model, for example:

```
            <Frame
                        WidthRequest="20"
                        HeightRequest="20"   
                        Margin="0,-30,0,10"
                        HorizontalOptions="End"
                        CornerRadius="10"
                        Padding="5"
                        BackgroundColor="{Binding SecondFrameBackColor}">
                <Label
                            Text="5"
                            TextColor="#FFFFFF"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalTextAlignment="Center"                                       
                    >

                </Label>
            </Frame>
```

Here is the model:

```
class myModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    Color firstFrameBackColor;

    Color secondFrameBackColor;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public myModel()
    {

    }

    public Color FirstFrameBackColor
    {
        set
        {
            if (firstFrameBackColor != value)
            {
                firstFrameBackColor = value;

                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FirstFrameBackColor"));
                }
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return firstFrameBackColor;
        }
    }

    public Color SecondFrameBackColor
    {
        set
        {
            if (secondFrameBackColor != value)
            {
                secondFrameBackColor = value;

                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SecondFrameBackColor"));
                }
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return secondFrameBackColor;
        }
    }
}
```

The itemSoure:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    ObservableCollection<myModel> models = new ObservableCollection<myModel>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myModel model1 = new myModel() { FirstFrameBackColor = Color.White, SecondFrameBackColor = Color.Purple };
        myModel model2 = new myModel() { FirstFrameBackColor = Color.White, SecondFrameBackColor = Color.Purple };
        myModel model3 = new myModel() { FirstFrameBackColor = Color.White, SecondFrameBackColor = Color.Purple };
        myModel model4 = new myModel() { FirstFrameBackColor = Color.White, SecondFrameBackColor = Color.Purple };
        myModel model5 = new myModel() { FirstFrameBackColor = Color.White, SecondFrameBackColor = Color.Purple };
        myModel model6 = new myModel() { FirstFrameBackColor = Color.White, SecondFrameBackColor = Color.Purple };
        myModel model7 = new myModel() { FirstFrameBackColor = Color.White, SecondFrameBackColor = Color.Purple };

        models.Add(model1);
        models.Add(model2);
        models.Add(model3);
        models.Add(model4);
        models.Add(model5);
        models.Add(model6);
        models.Add(model7);

        CNlist.ItemsSource = models;
    }
```

And in the `SelectionChanged` event, change the background to what you want:

```
private void CNlist_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{

    myModel previous = (e.PreviousSelection.FirstOrDefault() as myModel) ;
    myModel current = (e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as myModel);

    //Set the current to the color you want
    current.FirstFrameBackColor = Color.Pink;
    current.SecondFrameBackColor = Color.Green;

    if (previous != null)
    {
        //Reset the previous to defaulr color
        previous.FirstFrameBackColor = Color.White;
        previous.SecondFrameBackColor = Color.Purple;
    }

}
```

Here is the result:

[image: screen]

I updated my sample [here](https://github.com/XfHua/collectionView-binding-xamarin.forms) and you can check it. Let me know if it works to you!

Comment: i already did this i only want to change the background of my frame not the whole stacklayout in ur case u r changing the background color of whole stacklayout which i already tried

Comment: @MastiBrozTop Please check my updated answer. You can mark it if it solves you problem.

Comment: @MastiBrozTop I does not see any code. Where is your model class? Just add the property to your itemSource.

Comment: please check my question again i edit my question @jackhua_msft

Comment: @MastiBrozTop That means you are not get a correct `current` as FrameModel. Check the current and what element is in your itemSource.

Comment: check my question again i have added my xaml code but i tried what u said but it is not working

Comment: @MastiBrozTop Define classesInfos as ObservableCollection. And is your viewModel implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface?

Comment: please check my question again i have posted the code

Comment: @MastiBrozTop What's the code in your OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged? Did you get the right current? Add a breadpoint there to check.

Comment: yes i am getting the right current and i also debug the firstframebackgroundcolor which call from frame model class but its not changing the background color

Comment: Did you set binding to FirstFrameBackColor in the xaml? I saw your binding path is FrameBackColor in the xaml. Dose the Class_name binding successfully? Will the backgroundColor change if you give a default value to FirstFrameBackColor ?

Comment: i just change my frame model class in to your model class and its working now thanks

Comment: can i change the label color using binding context like this ?

Comment: @MastiBrozTop Yes, it is the same.

Comment: @MastiBrozTop 3 mistakes there: 1. `PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("labelcolor"));`  LabelColor instead of labelcolor. 2.  `return firstFrameBackColor; ` , return txtcolor  instead of firstFrameBackColor. 3 current.LabelColor = Color.Black;, it should be previous.LabelColor = Color.Black;.

Answer (score 0):

From the [CollectionView Spec:](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/5622#issuecomment-478171083)

> The orange color is actually the value for state_activated in your
>   Android app's theme. So not everyone will see orange; that's just the
>   AppCompat default. This is the fallback value if nothing else has been
>   specified.
>
> When an item in the CollectionView is selected, the VisualState for
>   the root Forms element of the item is changed to Selected. You can use
>   the VisualStateManager to manage what a selected item looks like. For
>   an example of this, take a look at the SelectionModeGallery in Control
>   Gallery. On that page, the background color for the selected item is
>   being set to LightSkyBlue. Any other Forms property can also be set;
>   for instance, try adding  to
>   the  tag.
>
> At the moment, this is somewhat limited; you can really only modify
>   the root element in your ItemTemplate.

So, to answer your question, it will not work, since your Frame is not the Root element from your ItemTemplate. Either you apply that in your StackLAyout, or in the SelectedItem, you change manually the background color of your element.

Comment: when i set my root element as frame it changes the background color of frame but the remaining keeps orange

Comment: and when i give x:name property to my child views inside the collection view i cant access them in my C# class